# dynamic or static database tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, table

I am creating a little mulitplayer game. The game creates a session where players can join in. Then the session has to store some data provided in the game.

Should I create a new session table dynamically or a one table with the col sessionId where I store the data from all sessions?

Easier and better structured would be the dynamic solution, but I have heard this is not the best practise.

Comment: Don't create a table for each session. Using one table with the session ID as the key is a good idea.

Comment: ok I will do so. But what specifically is the downside a dynamically created tables

Comment: There's quite a bit of overhead when creating a table and very very seldom is it a good idea to dynamically create tables. Any time you think you need to do it it is time to step back and think things through again. It would also be a nightmare to keep up with all of the tables that could end up being created.

Comment: makes sense, thanks for the fast response

Comment: You don't buy a new briefcase every day you go to the office, only to throw it away at the end of day. You keep your briefcase even if it's empty, to use the next day.

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases in general, but specifically MySQL are thought to have a static structure. Let me elaborate a bit on what static entails (as it doesn't necessarily mean immutable):

> Each version of the application should work with a predefined set of
>   tables and internal structure

Only when requirements change (be it functional or things like performance improvements) you will perform an application "migration" to adapt the logic and data to the new ones, and add, delete or `ALTER` existing tables. If your table structure changes frequently (compared to the number of read and write operations), that is normally a sign of a bad design.

In particular, new users or state of an application (sessions), should not create new sets of tables, but add rows to existing ones.

As exceptions, Schema-based [Multi-tenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) is a pattern that would fit the "creation of a new database" for each "application user group", but normally the scope of that is new organizations sharing the same software, or separate communities that require separate configuration; and normally with things like **security or cost in mind**. For sessions, [table-based multi-tenancy](https://vladmihalcea.com/database-multitenancy/) is probably the most common pattern.

Dynamicaly **creating and deleting tables usually has a high cost compared to inserting and deleting rows**, specially on MySQL (creation of new tablespaces, invalidating high regions of memory, extra metadata locking, etc.)